# Unicast cluster may not function correctly as the listen address of server server1 is not specified

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic

Okay, I'm a COMPLETE amateur at persistence units, and I know not where to start here.  It seems to be insinuating I haven't wired things up properly, which is probably true.  Unfortunately, Searching for the error message produces either almost-nothing (in quotes), or absolutely everything in the world.   Where should I be looking?

```
<persistence version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="statusEJB" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jhuDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <class>weston.homework.beans.Course</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="NONE"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/examples;create=true"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is related with your weblogic setup rather than the persistence unit.

You can find further information here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/core.1111/e10113/chapter_bea_messages.htm#FMERR213